# Format text differently after line break <br>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to format a text differently within a "p" tag with a class. There is a line break by "br" and the following text should be formatted differently.
Is there a solution for this from css?
Below is the code example.

To-Do:
Format ${getDate(loadStoredTasks())}" different to ${zaehlerRechner(loadStoredTasks())}

```
<div class="list-task-responsible">
   <img src="img/energy-consumption_light.png"/>
   <p class="list-task-notes">${zaehlerRechner(loadStoredTasks())} <br> 
   ${getDate(loadStoredTasks())}</p>
</div>
```

[image]

**800,10 kWh**: is correct

**17.11.2022 - 20.11.2022**: should have other format (should look like: 17.11.2022 - 20.11.2022)

Comment: No there is not. You would have to use Js to wrap the required text in a `span` and then style *that*.

Comment: which coding you are using , are you using angular also, check question tags & explain in simple language , this is some confusion

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line you could make a rule in general for the `.list-task-notes` (addressing the dates part) and then style bold the first line for that class (addressing the kWh part)

Comment: Did you try first-line? @

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may wrap the second line in its own element set all the style you need to that element, e.g.

```css
.list-task-notes {
   font: 2rem/1 system-ui;
}

.list-task-notes small {
   font-size: 50%;
}
```

```html
<p class="list-task-notes">
  800,10 kWh<br> 
  <small>17.11.2022 – 20.11.2022</small>
</p>
```

Or you could use the `::first-line` pseudoselector to change the formatting of the first line (here's a [list of the allowed style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter#allowable_properties) for this psuedoselector)

```css
.list-task-notes {
   font: 1rem/1.5 system-ui;
}

.list-task-notes::first-line {
   font-size: 200%;
}
```

```html
<p class="list-task-notes">
      800,10 kWh<br> 
      17.11.2022 – 20.11.2022
    </p>
```

Comment: I note that CSS rules using `::first-line` can only use [a small subset of CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line#allowable_properties), which may-or-may-not be what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

like this? but ::first-line is only effective for first line, like it named

```
.list-task-notes{
    font-weight: normal;
}
.list-task-notes::first-line {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line

Answer (score 0):

You can try `div p::first-line{ /*Some styling here*/ }`